# What's the most efficient way to change the last element in a '/' delimited string

Tags: c#

I have a string object in c# with a bunch of elements delimited by '/' characters.  The string will look something like this:

"element1/element2/element3/element4"

What's the most efficient way to change the last element in the '/' delimited string?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [**`string.LastIndexOf`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w96zd3d.aspx):

```
string s = "element1/element2/element3/element4";
s = s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf('/') + 1) + "foo";
```

Comment: heh that is exactly the idea ^^

Comment: Hey, that's a pretty clever solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If this is a filename/path string, you should use the `System.IO.Path` for this.

Answer (score 1):

is there a 'lastIndexOf' in the C# String class? ( I don't code in C# normally ), if it exists you could use that to get a reference to the last / in the string, and that / precedes the last element of your string.

Answer (score 0):

Like Joel suggests.. maybe something like this:

```
     string path = (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(@"element1/element2/element3/element4") +
        System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "foo");
     string new_path = path.Replace(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, '/');
```